# Existence of an $L^2$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f_n \in L^2([0,1])$ be non-zero for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Prove there exists a function $g \in L^2([0,1])$ such that

$$\int_0^1 g(x) f_n(x) dx \neq 0.$$

So first I tried contradiction which implies $g(x)f_n(x)$ need be zero almost everywhere which would imply $g$ to be the zero function. But then again I thought maybe $g(x)=1$ on the whole unit interval could work? Its certainly in $L^2$...

Comment: Is $n$ an index for a sequence of functions?

Comment: yes it rangers over the natruals @whpowell96

Comment: Do you want $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad\int_0^1 g(x) f_n(x) dx \neq 0?$$ And do you assume $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad f_n\ne0?$$ Please edit your post to clarify **both points**, instead of answering in comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval for all $n \in \Bbb{N}, f_n \neq 0$..

Comment: edited @AnneBauval

Comment: For $g = 1$, take $f_n = 1-2x$.

Comment: Can $g$ be dependent on $n$, or do you want a $g$, s.t. the equation holds for any $n$?

Comment: I want a $g$ that works for any $n$ @tychonovs-scholar

Comment: Please re-edit your post to specify it also (as asked in my comment above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, put
$$U_n:=\{g \in L^2: \int_0^1 gf_n \neq 0\}.$$
Next, define linear functionals $L_n$ on $L^2$ via
$$L_n(g):=\int gf_n dx.$$
Then $U_n=L^{-1}(\{0\})^c$. And by continuity of $L_n$, $U_n$ is open as it is the preimage of an open set. Moreover, given any scalar $t$,
\begin{align*}
    L_n(g+tf_n)&=L_n(g)+tL_n(f_n)\\
    &=L_n(g) + t\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert^2.
\end{align*}
And since $\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert \neq 0$, there exists only one value of $t$ for which
$$g+tf_n \not\in U_n.$$
Thus $U_n$ is dense. Thus $(U_n)_n$ is a countable family of dense sets in $L^2([0,1])$ which is complete thus by Baire Category theorem,
$$\bigcap_n U_n \neq \emptyset.$$
And any $g \in \cap_n U_n$ has the property that
$$\int_0^1 gf_n dx \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

The hyperplanes $f_n^\perp$ are nowhere dense in the complete space $H:=L^2([0,1])$, hence by Baire's category theorem, their union does not cover $H$.

Comment: I could easily guess who was the first downvoter and I didn't care, but the second downvote makes me wonder: what is wrong with this answer? Is it not detailed enough? Or shouldn't I have posted it because you think the question was below the quality standards of this site?